# Declaration of reference variable requires an initializer

Tags: c++

I have reduced my real program to a toy example.

Say I have the following code:

```
struct A
{
  A( string i ) { }
  A( string *i ) { }
};

int main()
{
  string s;
  A("HELLO"); // Works
  A(&s); // XCode: Declaration of reference variable 's' requires an initializer
  // Visual Studio: error C2040: 's': 'A &' differs in levels of indirection from 'std::string'
}
```

I don't understand the error message. What does XCode mean "Declaration of reference variable 's' requires an initializer"? Why does `A("HELLO");` work while `A(&s)` does not?

Answer (score 7):

This is a phenomenon called *most-vexing parse*.

C++ treats `A(&s);` as a declaration of a variabled called `s`, whose type is `A&`. This won't work for several reasons:

- References need to be initialized, and you are not initializing `s` in this example (note: this `s` is not the same `s` as the one from 2 lines before).
- You already have a variable called `s` in the same scope, so this would be a redefinition.

To create an even smaller example, take a look at these two, equivalent lines of code that both declare a variable called `x` of type `int`:

```
int x;
int(x);
```

To fix the issue, you can simply use a proper declaration that uses the desired constructor, which doesn't suffer from the most-vexing parse problem:

```
A x1(&s); // this
auto x2 = A(&s); // or this
A{&s}; // or this, just to create a temporary
```

Comment: Note that in C++11 or later, `A{&s};` will be parsed correctly.